# Why is my OpenGL version always 2.1 on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, opengl, glfw

I'm using GLFW 3.0 on Mac OS X 10.8, graphic card is Intel HD Graphics 5000

And my OpenGL API version is 2.1, aquired by

```
glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR);
glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR);
```

Compiling options:

```
g++ ... -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit ...
```

Headers:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
```

The version is always 2.1, unlike [the reported 3.2](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_general/opengl_gen_tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH211-SW7). My OS has been upgraded to 10.9, and OpenGL version is still 2.1.

It still cannot compile GLSL 3.3, while [Apple says it supports 4.1](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823).  How do I access higher versions of the library?

Comment: glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE); To write before creating your window.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant : I tried this, and it leads to a failure in `glfwCreateWindow`.

Comment: Try glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2); // opengl 3.2 or glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1); // opengl 3.1  .It would crash only when the opengl version is not supported by OS X.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant : The same result...

Comment: Just because you upgraded your operating system does not mean you can use OpenGL 4.1... you need the appropriate version of the MacOS X Platform SDK. More than likely what you _really_ need to do is upgrade Xcode as well. There is a setting in the Xcode IDE that allows you to choose the default SDK that the commandline toolchain uses, I cannot remember where it is off the top of my head unfortunately.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman : I did upgrade XCode, otherwise it could not even compile&link the code.

Comment: To @PierreEmmanuelLallemant : I finally figured it out, I answered myself. And you were close to it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to add both "forward_compat" and "core_profile" hints before creating the window.

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL );
```

Comment: Saved my life (was not going to eat before I solved this issue).