# GLFW can't create 4.3 context

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I've begun using OpenGL via C++ and GLFW, but calls to `glfwCreateWindow(...)` aren't creating a context using the latest version of OpenGL available on my system (currently 4.3).
I've used OpenGL 4.3 contexts before with Java and LWJGL, but since switching to GLFW I've been unsuccessful.

Adding calls to

```
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
```

causes `glfwCreateWindow(...)` to return an error code, though changing the minor version to 2 works fine. Adding window hints to use a core profile and setting forward-compatibility to true also have no effect.

Does anyone know what the cause of it might be/a solution to this problem?

Edit: This is on Windows 7.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be making glfw API calls before calling `glfwInit (...)`. You want to set the Window Hints before creating your window, not before initializing the library ;)

Comment: The initialisation could be a little bit longer than your two lines: problem solved for opengl 3.2/3.3 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658745/why-is-my-opengl-version-always-2-1-on-mac-os-x?noredirect=1#comment29233630_19658745

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Sorry, that was a typo. My code calls that before the hints.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant I've tried specifying a core profile and forward-compatibility, but still doesn't work.

Comment: The solution should be near of its code, maybe other constants to use.

Comment: Have you tried using `glfwSetErrorCallback` to get a hint at the what the problem could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);  // yes, 3 and 2!!!
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

And you can use OpenGL 4.x anyways...

Why?

Check the [FAQ](http://www.glfw.org/faq.html) -- "4.1 - How do I create an OpenGL 3.0+ context?"

Comment: Thanks! Though querying the GL version returns 3.2, I'm still able to use 4.3 features (eg. compute shaders).