# Why is OpenGL giving me the error: ERROR: 0:1: '' : version '330' is not supported?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, shader

I am on mac and I am using Xcode 10.1 as I can't get a new version as my mac is on 10.13.6. I am new to C++ and OpenGL so I followed a tutorial on how to do this, but it is on Windows 10 so maybe that is the problem? It is using GLFW and GLEW both installed with Homebrew.

Here is my code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>

static unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& source)
{
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);
    
    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if(result == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message);
        std::cout << "Failed to compile " << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment") << " shader!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
        glDeleteShader(id);
        return 0;
    }
    
    return id;
}

static unsigned int CreateShader(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader)
{
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);
    
    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);
    
    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);
    
    return program;
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;
    
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Window", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    
    float positions[6] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.0f, 0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f
    };
    
    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);
    
    std::string vertexShader =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "\n"
    "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   glPosition = position;\n"
    "}\n";
    
    std::string fragmentShader =
    "#version 450 core\n"
    "\n"
    "layout(location = 0) out vec4 colour;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   colour = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n";
    
    unsigned int shader = CreateShader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    glUseProgram(shader);
    
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code the console writes this:

```
2.1 NVIDIA-10.4.14 310.90.30.05b27
Failed to compile vertex shader!
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '330' is not supported
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: #version
ERROR: 0:3: 'layout' : syntax error: syntax error

Failed to compile fragment shader!
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '450' is not supported
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: #version
ERROR: 0:3: 'layout' : syntax error: syntax error

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I suspect [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658745/why-is-my-opengl-version-always-2-1-on-mac-os-x) could be related.

Answer (score 7):

I'm macos 10.13.6, following `the cherno`'s lesson, meet your trouble too.

I finish by doing 2 step:

1. add these line of code in front of `glCreateWindow`

```
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
#ifdef __APPLE__
  cout << "I'm apple machine" << endl;
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif
```

2. add VAO as @Ali ASkari memtion above

finally:

```
  GLFWwindow *window;
  if (!glfwInit()) {
    cout << "glfw init err" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
#ifdef __APPLE__
  cout << "I'm apple machine" << endl;
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif
  unsigned int width = 800;
  unsigned int height = 600;
  window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Learngl", NULL, NULL);
  if (!window) {
    cout << " can't create window!!!" << endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
  }
  unsigned int major = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR);
  unsigned int minor = glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR);
  cout << "oepngl shader version: " << major << "." << minor << endl;
  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

  if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    cout << "Error ! " << endl;
  }
  cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << endl;

  float positions[6] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.0f,  0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,
  };
  unsigned int VBO, VAO;
  glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
  glBindVertexArray(VAO);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6*sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
  glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float)*2, 0);

  string vertexShader = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = position;\n"
    "}\0";
  string fragmentShader = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5f);\n"
    "}\n\0";
  unsigned int shader = CreateShader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
  glUseProgram(shader);

  while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    glfwPollEvents();
  }
  glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
  glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
  glDeleteProgram(shader);
  glfwTerminate();
```

Comment: Makes sense. from the glfw source code, the function _glfwCreateContextNSGL() mentions the following:

"NSGL: The targeted version of macOS only supports forward-compatible core profile contexts for OpenGL 3.2 and above"

Answer (score 1):

Your c++ code style is the same as the older version of opengl(3.2 and older) and is not compatible with your shaders. You have two options. One is to downgrade your shaders to the old version. Another way is to update the C++ codes. a correct example of opengl 3.30 is like this:

```
#include <iostream>

// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


// Function prototypes
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);

// Window dimensions
const GLuint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

// Shaders
const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}\0";
const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n\0";

// The MAIN function, from here we start the application and run the game loop
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Starting GLFW context, OpenGL 3.3" << std::endl;
    // Init GLFW
    glfwInit();
    // Set all the required options for GLFW
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    // Create a GLFWwindow object that we can use for GLFW's functions
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Set the required callback functions
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    // Set this to true so GLEW knows to use a modern approach to retrieving function pointers and extensions
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    // Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
    glewInit();

    // Define the viewport dimensions
    int width, height;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);  
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);


    // Build and compile our shader program
    // Vertex shader
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    // Check for compile time errors
    GLint success;
    GLchar infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // Fragment shader
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    // Check for compile time errors
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    // Link shaders
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    // Check for linking errors
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);


    // Set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and attribute pointers
    //GLfloat vertices[] = {
    //  // First triangle
    //   0.5f,  0.5f,  // Top Right
    //   0.5f, -0.5f,  // Bottom Right
    //  -0.5f,  0.5f,  // Top Left 
    //  // Second triangle
    //   0.5f, -0.5f,  // Bottom Right
    //  -0.5f, -0.5f,  // Bottom Left
    //  -0.5f,  0.5f   // Top Left
    //}; 
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // Top Right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // Bottom Right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // Bottom Left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f   // Top Left 
    };
    GLuint indices[] = {  // Note that we start from 0!
        0, 1, 3,  // First Triangle
        1, 2, 3   // Second Triangle
    };
    GLuint VBO, VAO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    // Bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s) and attribute pointer(s).
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); // Note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the currently bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind

    glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO (it's always a good thing to unbind any buffer/array to prevent strange bugs), remember: do NOT unbind the EBO, keep it bound to this VAO


    // Uncommenting this call will result in wireframe polygons.
    //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    // Game loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Check if any events have been activiated (key pressed, mouse moved etc.) and call corresponding response functions
        glfwPollEvents();

        // Render
        // Clear the colorbuffer
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Draw our first triangle
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        // Swap the screen buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    // Properly de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
    // Terminate GLFW, clearing any resources allocated by GLFW.
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// Is called whenever a key is pressed/released via GLFW
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}
```

A big difference between the old version and the new versions is the need to use VAO in the new version.

Comment: **need to use VAO in the new version** this piece of information helped me, while I was trying to make https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71BLZwRGUJE&list=PLlrATfBNZ98foTJPJ_Ev03o2oq3-GGOS2&index=7 work on macOS

Comment: It seems to me the issue is discussed on https://youtu.be/Bcs56Mm-FJY?list=PLlrATfBNZ98foTJPJ_Ev03o2oq3-GGOS2&t=551

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem when trying to run my code on MacOs after developing on my Windows machine. I added the following logic to make it run on MacOs.

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```